# Creating Python websocket server

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, kdb

I am looking for a way to create a python websocket server.

I have read through the asyncio tutorial

https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

It seems quite complicated to me
I have done this in kdb and it is the easiest thing in the world.

Why does it seem to weirdly complicated in python

What i am trying to do exactly is have a python server that will push data to all its connected clients throughout the data

However, from that asyncio tutorial it seems each time a message is received from the client, the connection is closed (why on earth would they make it this way?)

I need the connection to remain open forever. I decide when its get closed.

The server will push data whenever it has to do so (by my logic)

Additionally, the client can request (other type of) data from the server

I would assume this is doable? But it doesnt seem so from that tutorial
Can anyone point me in a good direction? How do i do this properly?

Comment: what is `kdb` ? What so complex in examples in tutorial ? As I understand example - it closes only if you end function (when server has nothing more to send) but if you use `while True` then it keeps open.

Answer (score 0):

The `Consumer`, `Producer`, and `Both` examples under [Common patterns](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#common-patterns) accomplish exactly that. If you have specific questions, post your code with your issue.

Comment: I don't think that's the link you meant to post.

Comment: Thanks, but what i don't understand is this: